# How to update date field to Null based on another field value in siebel

Tags: siebel

I need to make date field to null based another field value.

I have tried using "On Field Update Set" with following value

```
"ACS Tax Exemption", "Tax Exemption Expiry Date", "", "[ACS Tax Exemption] = 'N'"
```

it did not work out.

Tools Version: Siebel 8.1

Comment: Have you set Immediate Post as true?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving """" for null in the expression.

Comment: Hi Ranjtih,
Thanks for the reply I have tried above but still it did not worked out.

"ACS Tax Exemption", "Tax Exemption Expiry Date", """", "[ACS Tax Exemption] = "N""

Answer (score 0):

Try [ACS Tax Exemption] <> 'Y',

but we need more info. Show screen of User Properties and your field property window in BC